# How to specify user location in ios simulator with Rubymotion

Tags: location, cllocation, rubymotion

I'm developing an iPhone app with RubyMotion and I would like to specify the user location when testing my app in the simulator.

Is there a way to use a .gpx file as I would have done in xcode ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that RubyMotion supports launching the app with Instruments, you can try this method: http://www.cardinalsolutions.com/cardinal/blog/mobile/2013/02/testing_a_location-a.html (written by my friend Rachel Parsons).

Ignore the xcode setup and skip down to where she talks about doing "automation" in Instruments.

To launch your app in instruments, simply run `rake profile`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to use a gpx file, but the simulator itself provides a way to define a user location.  You can specify a lat/long via the Debug | Location | Custom Location menu.

That's what I am using for my app, and it seems to work well.